# SharePoint Downloads

Tags: error

I'm trying to upload a file to SharePoint, but after it uploads, I get a redX and a message that says the file is checked out or locked by another user. This is impossible because the document is on my desktop. The other user has no access to this document. I have 5 similar files and had no issue. Help!

Comment: Does this happen when you upload to every Document Library, or just one in particular?

Comment: have you tried to create test file and upload it?